# Adding a new element to a JSON array using jq

Tags: json, jq

I want to add a new pair of values to an array that's nested within a couple of objects. I've tried various suggestions, but haven't been able to get things to line up properly.
Here's the JSON that I have.

```
{
    "FieldValues": [{
        "FieldName": "Groups",
        "Value": [{
                "Id": 641254,
                "Label": "S4"
            },{
                "Id": 642587,
                "Label": "S8"
            },
            {
                "Id": 641247,
                "Label": "S7"
            }
        ],
        "SystemCode": "Groups"
    }],
    "Id": 33034883
}
```

I need to add an Id-Label pair: `{"Id": 642587, "Label": "S8"}` in the `Value` array so that we get

```
{
    "FieldValues": [{
        "FieldName": "Groups",
        "Value": [{
                "Id": 641254,
                "Label": "S4"
            },{
                "Id": 642587,
                "Label": "S8"
            },
            {
                "Id": 641247,
                "Label": "S7"
            }
        ],
        "SystemCode": "Groups"
    }],
    "Id": 33034883
}
```

Note that `Id` within the array is a different critter from the one at the end of the object.
I've tried many different ways to get the items into the right level. For example, here's one that didn't work.

```
jq '. += {Value: [{Id: 8511657, "Label": "S8"}]}' current.json
```

Here's the (incorrect) result.

```
{
  "FieldValues": [
    {
      "FieldName": "Groups",
      "Value": [
        {
          "Id": 641254,
          "Label": "S4"
        },
        {
          "Id": 641247,
          "Label": "S7"
        }
      ],
      "SystemCode": "Groups"
    }
  ],
  "Id": 33034883,
  "Value": [
    {
      "Id": 8511657,
      "Label": "S8"
    }
  ]
}
```

Although it's valid JSON, the array layout doesn't work properly when I use it to update a record in our database. The final `Value` array is ignored.

Comment: Is there always only one Value array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution, I believe, would be:

```
.FieldValues[0].Value += [{Id: 8511657, "Label": "S8"}]
```

Notice that the LHS in effect specifies the path to the key whose value is to be updated.